# How do I filter the result of "Custom Text Field"?

Tags: views, 9

I have added a Custom Text field in a view that displays yes / No.

How can I filter the data using exposed filters where custom text field value is only yes / No.

I found that the Custom text field is not added in the SQL query. So, When I am working with the custom views filter I see an error column not found.